# Can Zookeeper run on dotcloud

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, dotcloud

I'm trying to run nutch, which needs gora which needs hbase which needs zookeeper.
Working backwards down to the hbase tutorial, here is my hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>file:///home/dotcloud/data/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/home/dotcloud/data/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Running hbase shell, I'm getting an error saying ...

```
hbase(main):001:0> 
hbase(main):002:0* create 'test', 'cf'
13/08/23 14:04:46 ERROR zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: ZooKeeper exists failed after 3 retries
13/08/23 14:04:46 WARN zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection Unable to set watcher on znode (/hbase/hbaseid)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid
```

From what [I can find](http://systemsarchitect.net/painless-guide-to-solr-cloud-configuration/) Zookeeper in standalone mode doesn't like the loopback device on 127.0.1.1 but there is no sudo access in dotcloud to change /etc/hosts

Is this the root of the problem or have I made a mistake somewhere else?
Can Zookeeper + Hbase + Gora + Nutch run on dotcloud?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone's already provided a recipe for zookeeper-on-dotcloud.  The last commit was about 6 months ago, so it might need some updating.

https://github.com/gabrielgrant/zookeeper-on-dotcloud

If you use this recipe or model the approach after theirs, does it resolve some of the problems you're encountering?